# How to pass a sentence between double quotes in bash when creating a function

Tags: bash, zsh

I am trying to create an alias which is a shorthand for `git commit -m "commit message"`.

What I was trying to do is create a function below in `~/.aliases`.

```
gc()
{
    git commit -m ""$@""
}
```

This give me this error message when I use this "alias" `gc install project`

```
error: pathspec 'install' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'project' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

while I was expecting it to be `git commit -m "install project"`

How can I make this alias work as I want it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the goal is to combine all the arguments to `gc` into a single string to use as the argument to `-m`, you want to use `$*`, not `$@`. Further, you don't need to specify the quotes. In `git commit -m "install project"`, the quotes are not part of the argument; they are just there to instruct `bash` that `install project` is a single word, not two separate words, to pass as an argument to `git`.

```
gc () {
    git commit -m "$*"
}
```

However, I would encourage you to take responsibility for passing a *single*, properly quoted argument to `gc`, so that you don't have to worry about what the shell will do to characters like `$`, `*`, etc.

```
gc () {
    git commit -m "$1"
}

gc "install my *awesome* project"
```